# Is anyone focusing on Mule with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mule

I have been using Spring Boot for a short while and it's great for getting things up and running quickly.

Is anyone working on a template for integrating Mule ESB with Spring Boot ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if Mule will be charge of this or not. But you can suggest this in the spring-boot project in [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues)

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be use queues , so mule expose a functionality as queue enpoint and spring boot send and receive string messages to mule queue. I have seen it work in complex scenarios.

Latency will increase but the core of integrations will remain in mule esb.

Other approaches:

- Starting mule programmatically from spring boot: http://glawson6.github.io/spring/mule/2015/04/22/using-spring-boot-with-mule.html (not tested)
- https://github.com/denschu/mule-spring-boot-starter(not tested)

HTH